# Routing to a specific page within a lazy-loaded module in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I have the following in my main app router:

`{ path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/modules/users/users.module#UsersModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] }`

When the user goes to http://localhost:4200/users/1234 to see their profile, I try to save the full url (including the user ID above) so that I would route back to that page once they're logged in.

The problem is, the `Route` parameter in the `canLoad` function only has a `path` field that does not include the user ID above, only the path `users`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

**EDIT AFTER FIRST COMMENT**

The users routing module does have a `canActivate` guard, but this never gets called except from the login component, since the first `canLoad` returned false and routed the caller to the login component previously.

**EDIT AFTER FIRST ANSWER**

```js
canLoad(route: Route) {
  if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
    this.router.events.takeWhile(event => !(event instanceof NavigationCancel))
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          AuthService.setRedirectUrl(event.url);
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

So I tried the above, but I think I'm doing something wrong still, since console never logs... how do I unsubscribe or stop receiving `NavigationCancel` events after I set store the redirect URL?

Comment: if you want to save the state in a guard, try using `canActivate` guard. Since canLoad is called
during the construction of the router state, and `canActivate` is called after, the canActivate guard
gets more information. It gets its activated route and the whole router state, whereas the canLoad
guard only gets the route.

Comment: Sure, but if `canLoad` fails in the first place, `canActivate` will never be called!

Comment: right, but if it fails, do you need to save the page still?

Comment: `canLoad` failed because the caller is not logged in. The caller then gets routed to a login component, which, after authenticating, should route the user to the original URL.

Comment: try injecting a router into a guard, subscribe to guard [events](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/router/src/router.ts#L326) and listen for [NavigationStart](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/router/src/events.ts#L17) or [RoutesRecognized](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/router/src/events.ts#L91) event

Comment: Thank you, and I do not need to unsubscribe from that? I remember reading that the exception to required unsubscribing was the router.

Comment: It's actually NavigationCancel that I should subscribe to by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `canLoad` is called during the construction of the router state it doesn't get activated route and the whole router state. It gets only the route.

You can inject a router into a guard, subscribe to [NavigationCancel](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/router/src/events.ts#L53) event where you can access the URL.

> how do I unsubscribe or stop receiving NavigationCancel events after I
>   set store the redirect URL?

Since [router.events is a Subject](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/router/src/router.ts#L222), you can unsubscribe from it like this:

```
// get the subscription reference
const subscription = this.router.events.takeWhile(event => !(event instanceof NavigationCancel))
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          AuthService.setRedirectUrl(event.url);
          // use it to unsubscribe
          subscription.unsubscribe(); <----------------------------
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer as well, I believe something is still missing, but I guess it has more to do with my observable operators in this case!

Comment: @Sammy, updated my answer with unsubscription recipe